# Collapsable Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new to jQuery and this is one of the first attempts to use it. Tell me if I am using it wrong:

This is the main code that toggles everything:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tree li").hide();//collapse everything by default

    $("#tree span").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("uncollapsed");//toggle "V" and ">"
        $(this).parent().find(">li").toggle("fast");//display and hide
    });
});
```

I am only interested to get reviews on the JS above, however, I will post the the HTML and CSS to give some background.

HTML:

```
<ul id="tree">
    <span>(click to toggle)</span>

    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <span>(click to toggle)</span>

            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#tree ul,#tree li,#tree span{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#tree li,#tree span{
    padding:5px 0 5px 20px;
}

#tree span{
    cursor:pointer;
    background:url('collapsed.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}

#tree span.uncollapsed{
    background-image:url('uncollapsed.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid html.

The only thing you can put inside a `<ul>` tag is `<li>` tags.

With that in mind, this would be much better (change the selector as necessary):

```
$("#tree span").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("uncollapsed").next().toggle("fast");
});
```

Otherwise, you should change the click method to:

```
$("#tree span").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("uncollapsed").parent().children("li").toggle("fast");
});
```

Reasons:

- you don't need to use $() over again to recreate $(this)
- `.find(">li")` is a less efficient version of `.children("li")`

Better yet, if you can change the html to:

```
<span class='hasChildren'>
    (click to toggle)
    <ul id="tree">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li class='hasChildren'>
            (click to toggle)
            <ul>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Then the click event to:

```
$(".hasChildren").click(function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("collapsed");
    return false;
});
```

And in css, style accordingly (you could even animate the class if you wished). Note however that this would be a change in the way the list worked (play around with `<a>` tags in the list and clicking in different parts to see the difference).